# How do I register permission handlers without using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Im trying to register permission handlers in a react native app that is using v59. All of the instructions im coming across provide steps for using Cocoapods, which im currently not using.

I came across a post [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions/issues/348#issuecomment-541423154) providing steps on how to manually copy the handler files into the project, but its still not being detected.

The error im getting is "No permission handler detected".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by moving the handlers to the library section of the code instead of the top level project.

[image]